# Android Appium performance issue after webelement.click()

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

Is there any reason whatsoever for huge performance issues after clicking an item that brings you up to another screen ?

I've successfully done some very nice and fast unit testing with `appium` in python over an android app. The problem is, everything works fast and fine, until I click an item that shows more products in a new screen. After that, every single call to `self.driver.find_element_by_id` or by whatever takes like 10 full seconds no matter what, before it was instant.

I did timing and performance testing, and after clicking the item with `.click()`, everything takes 10 full seconds to complete, which was instant before.

Is there any reason behind this that I'm missing ? Maybe because of switching to the new screen that might be a a different activity ?

Example:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("sticky") <= every call before this is pretty much instant
more_item.click()                        <= this click ruins everything
sleep(5)
self.driver.find_element_by_id("sticky") <= every call from now on, even if it's the same as above, takes 10 full seconds no matter what
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using self.find_element_by_id(***) use find_element_by_androidUIAutomator that will increase the response time of Appium for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up parsing the source xml page... I will give a try with byUIAutomator though, that's the only thing I never tried, but it's still wierd... the delay has nothing to do with the processing time... because it's a full 10 seconds, no matter what you search for... even by a single id... or by **, same time.